# How to install Cocorico?

Tags: php, mongodb, symfony, composer-php

I'm currently installing [Cocorico](https://github.com/Cocolabs-SAS/cocorico) an open source solution to create marketplaces for services.

My environment is Ubuntu 18.04, PHP 7.1, Apache 2, MySQL and MongoDB 4.

When i run `composer install` i have the following error:

```
Problem 1
 - Installation request for alcaeus/mongo-php-adapter 1.1.3 -> satisfiable by alcaeus/mongo-php-adapter[1.1.3].
 - alcaeus/mongo-php-adapter 1.1.3 requires ext-mongodb ^1.2.0 -> the requested PHP extension mongodb is missing from your system.

Problem 2
 - Installation request for mongodb/mongodb 1.2.0 -> satisfiable by mongodb/mongodb[1.2.0].
 - mongodb/mongodb 1.2.0 requires ext-mongodb ^1.3.0 -> the requested PHP extension mongodb is missing from your system.
```

It seems that php mongodb extension is missing. But i can see it in my php  installed modules:

```
> php -m
...
mbstring
mongo
...
```

How can i make composer aware of the installed mongo PHP extension?

Thanks!

Comment: What does `composer show -p` output? Also, are you by chance using Docker?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is showing you have the **mongo** extension, which is apparently [deprecated](http://php.net/manual/en/mongo.installation.php) and should be **mongodb**. Check this out [from the mongo docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/ecosystem/drivers/php/):

> The mongo extension available from PECL is an older, legacy driver for PHP 5.x. The mongo extension is no longer maintained and new projects are advised to use the mongodb extension and PHP library. A community-developed Mongo PHP Adapter project implements the legacy mongo extension’s API using the new mongodb extension and PHP library, which may be useful for those wishing to migrate existing applications.

Installation for **mongodb** extension per the PHP docs can be found [here](http://php.net/manual/en/set.mongodb.php). It basically says to do this with PECL:

```
sudo pecl install mongodb
```

Then add `extension=mongodb.so` to your *php.ini* file.

Or you can try this (may vary depending on PHP version and PPA you are using):

```
sudo apt-get install php-mongodb
```

Comment: @Tsounabe did this help you resolve the mongodb extension issue? If so, can please mark the answer as accepted when you get a chance? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to start with cocorico is withh docker.
https://github.com/Cocolabs-SAS/cocorico-docker